# When will StackApps be featured in the OData Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, stackapps

I've been eagerly waiting for StackApps to finally be included in the data dump and now it has. But it still is not included in the OData Explorer, which is a real shame, becuase I noticed that WebApps and the SF/SU Metas are included now.

Waffles, can you please add it?

Comment: sure ... for next months dump

Comment: @waffles: If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the best answer and upvote it.

Comment: yeah ... but then I will forget to do this :) Ill take the credit when I complete it

Comment: I've been hoping to look at **Area51 data**; I still haven't written the questions I want to ask about proposal trends. such as the correlation between beta-and-beyond success and commitment rate.

Comment: @Mark: Please vote for [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/1234/why-i-think-area51-needs-an-api) then.

Answer (score 2):

.................................NOW!

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackapps/queries

Comment: Yes, it's been there for a while now :)